# Cause of P0440 on 1999 Subaru Legacy Outback

Tags: subaru, cel, fuel-tank

I get a P0440 code on my Outback on almost every highway trip over 5 miles. Is this caused by the leak in the gas tank or could it be something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by a number of things, including:

- Leak in the fuel tank (loose cap)
- Leaking evaporator canister (plastic housing in engine compartment or under vehicle, also known as charcoal canister)
- Plugged evaporator canister - there is a tube that is open to the air that can become plugged
- Malfunctioning purge valve - valve itself is faulty or wiring to the valve is faulty
- Malfunctioning sensor - The whole system may be working just fine, but the sensor that *monitors* the system may be faulty. It checks for pressure or vacuum at key times while driving to make a guess about how well everything is working.

So, everything from a $5 gas cap (free, if it's just loose), to a very expensive fuel tank can cause this one.

Comment: Good to know. I know the tank definitely has a leak around the 3/4 mark so that's likely the cause then.

Comment: Hey, I think I have the same problem, Subaru imprezza, though.